# Swiftui continue with Facebook failed

Tags: swiftui, facebook-login

I'm creating a new app using swiftui, I've added "continue with Facebook" login option, however I'm getting the below error when I press the button, how can i fix it? any help?

error message:

> Thread 1: "As of v9.0, you must initialize the SDK prior to calling any methods or setting any properties. You can do this by calling `FBSDKApplicationDelegate`'s `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. Learn more: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started%22)

code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit

@main
struct FirstApp: App {
     
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup { 
            ContentView()
                .onOpenURL(perform: { url in
                    ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
                            UIApplication.shared,
                            open: url,
                            sourceApplication: nil,
                            annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
                        )
                })
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)` as it shows in step 4 of the documentation.

Comment: Issue fixed!! thanks man